# How to configure Clion, so that inlay type-hints show up in Rust code?

Tags: rust, clion, type-hinting

im using clion to program rust (latest versions of clion and rust plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8182-rust). im trying to get inferred types to show up automatically in the editor fx.

```
let x: *i32* = 1;
```

where the "*i32*" is inferred when i write "let x = 1;". this however does not happen, i only get to see the "*i32*" when mouse hovering over the "x" but the "*i32*" is not (dynamically) inserted into the code. i have enabled all the "hints" in clion preferences but nothing works, any ideas? do i need another plugin to make this happen? thanks

Comment: A "hint" is only a hint in the IDE itself, not something that will be inserted into the code. You need to look at refactoring or transformation options if you want actual in-code changes.

Comment: thanks, but in vs code with rust-analyzer, the type info can be inserted automatically. so you think it should be called a refactoring option? but actually the code is not refactored, the type info is just shown as if you wrote it yourself (albeit in another color). any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have functions on generic types/traits and higher order functions, many of the types can't be inferred until the function sees a tangible return value. In those cases, I often add a dummy return value matching the type I want, which can help it infer the types in a backward direction rather than forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is "Inlay Hints", which should be enabled by default.

The option is in `Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> Rust -> Type hints`

#### Settings panel:

[image: Settings panel]

#### Result:

[image: Inlay Type Hints example]

Comment: Also, the specific one for the question is "Show for variables"

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what i did, strangely, it does not work. so probably a bug (latest versions of mac os, clion, rust plugin).